# ClueBringer (PolicyD) user manual

Tags: spf, manual

Is there some user manual for ClueBringer (PolicyD) where I can learn how to setup policies, limitations and use other features. Webui looks intuitive, but policies I setup does not work.
So, any kind of instructions should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php?page=Documentation for some documentation on this project.